# How to include a dynamic variable inside a htmx request?

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I have an endpoint which accepts an ID as parameter.
Ex : mysite.com/product/{id}?limit=5

How to pass the variable 'id' in the hx-get ?
(Can use AlpineJS or vanilla JS)

`<button hx-trigger="click" hx-get="mysite.com/product/{id}?limit=5">Send</button>`
Do I need htmx.process ? How to use it ?

Comment: Shouldn't the param be populated by the backend in your template? Is there any specific reasoning to pass variable on the frontend?

Comment: @mariodev yes it's simple, I don't have backend. The id variable is populated by an input form (using js). The backend is an outside API

Answer (score 1):

Edit:
thanks to Mark Volkmann input. I added `x-effect="id;htmx.process($el)"`. this makes htmx reevaluate the element when the id change.

Alpine example

```html
<div x-data="{id:123}">
    <button :hx-get="`/product/${id}?limit=5`" x-effect="id;htmx.process($el)">Send</button>
</div>
```

using [x-bind](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/bind) shorthand on hx-get attribute. the value is just js string interpolation with the provided id.

Comment: This approach doesn't work if the value of the Alpine `id` variable changes. It will always pass the original value of `id` to the endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I learned two more approaches to solve this yesterday.
Both rely on the "htmx:configRequest" event.
I documented them at https://mvolkmann.github.io/blog/topics/#/blog/htmx/.
Click the "Dynamic Endpoints" link in the table of contents in section 26.

Answer (score 0):

To trigger htmx request on the frontend side you should use `htmx.ajax`

Ref: https://htmx.org/api/#ajax